# Mixed data type case expression PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to do a case expression with mixed data types with no avail. Please could I get some help with what I'm doing wrong, please see my statement below

```
Case 
   when c.student_age > 19 
     and c.count_forms > 3 
     and ss.value :: date <@ fiscal_year.f_year 
       then "Y" 
   else "N" 
end as student_r_year
```

I'm using both int and date data in the first part of the case statement and that's where the issue is.

Comment: The data type of the expression is determined by the expressions after the `THEN` and the `ELSE` -  not those used to evaluate the expression. What is the error you get? Do you really have a column named `"Y"`- or do you want to return a string constant? `'Y'` is a string constant, `"Y"` is an identifier.

Comment: Hi,  I want to return a string constant "Y" or "N" depending if the first part is true, i.e. age, count and the date is within the fiscal year.

Comment: The error that I get is; "ERROR operator does not exist: @ date range"

Comment: Did you mean to write `ss.value::date < fiscal_year.f_year`? What data type is `ss.value`. And as I have already mentioned `"Y"` is not a string constant. Those need single quotes, e.g. `'Y'`

Comment: Hi, apologies, in my script it's written at 'Y', somebody when I'm typing I keep using double quotes. as.value is an answer column with mixed data, text, int and dates, however I already have a where clause that limits the value to the dates and this come out correctly in the output. I need the '< @' as "fiscal_year.f_year" is a date range

Comment: I have just tried removing the date cast from ss.value and this seemed to have worked ... I'm not sure why :/.

Comment: What data type is ss.value?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the definition of <@, but from your description, I assume that you  mean that ss.value is the same year as fiscal_year.f_year:

```
Case 
   when c.student_age > 19 
     and c.count_forms > 3 
     and ss.value :: date BETWEEN (fiscal_year.f_year::varchar || '-01-01')::date 
                              AND (fiscal_year.f_year::varchar || '-12-31')::date
   then 'Y' 
   else 'N' 
end as student_r_year
```

An alternative is to extract the year from ss.value:

```
Case 
   when c.student_age > 19 
     and c.count_forms > 3 
     and extract(year from ss.value :: date) = fiscal_year.f_year
   then 'Y' 
   else 'N' 
end as student_r_year
```

Comment: The `@>` is the "contains" operator https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html

Comment: or array operator or jsonb or tsquery or something else or even user-defined one. In postgresql, there is simply no "just operator" - an operator is identified by its operand types. In a pure pg13 database, there are 13 different `@>` operators and 16 `<@`. `\do <@` meta command in psql will show the list.